# image analysis curve fitting

Tags: python, image-processing, curve-fitting

I have a bunch of images like this one:

[image]

The corresponding data is not available. I need to automatically retrieve about 100 points (regularly x-spaced) on the blue curve. All curves are very similar, so I need at least 1 pixel precision, but sub-pixel would be preferred. The good news is all curves start from 0,0 and end at 1,1, so we may forget about the grid.

Any hint on Python libs that could help or any other approach ? Thanks !

Comment: Interesting question, I'm working on a solution, but sub-pixel precision is unlikely.

Comment: Only semi-automatic but still relevant to the question, this web app can do wonders: http://arohatgi.info/WebPlotDigitizer/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I saved your image to a file `14154233_input.png`. Then this program

```
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np

# Read image from disk and filter all grayscale
im = plt.imread("14154233_input.png")[:,:,:3]
im -= im.mean(axis=2).reshape(im.shape[0], im.shape[1], 1).repeat(3,axis=2)
im_maxnorm = im.max(axis=2)

# Find y-position of remaining line
ypos = np.ones((im.shape[1])) * np.nan
for i in range(im_maxnorm.shape[1]):
    if im_maxnorm[:,i].max()<0.01:
        continue
    ypos[i] = np.argmax(im_maxnorm[:,i])

# Pick only values that are set
ys = 1-ypos[np.isfinite(ypos)]
# Normalize to 0,1
ys -= ys.min()
ys /= ys.max()

# Create x values
xs = np.linspace(0,1,ys.shape[0])

# Create plot of both 
# read and filtered image and
# data extracted
plt.figure(figsize=(4,8))
plt.subplot(211)
plt.imshow(im_maxnorm)
plt.subplot(212, aspect="equal")
plt.plot(xs,ys)
plt.show()
```

Produces this plot:

[image: Ausgabe]

You can then do with `xs` and `ys` whatever you want. Maybe you should put this code in a function that returns xs and ys or so.

One could improve the precision by fitting gaussians on each column or so. If you really need it, tell me.

Comment: I'm not practical with pylab, can I ask you to explain how the `im -= im.mean(axis=2).reshape(im.shape[0], im.shape[1], 1).repeat(3,axis=2)` line works?

Comment: Sure. imread gives us an RGBA image, i.e., our array has shape (x,y,4), which I immediately reduce by discarding alpha ([:,:,:3] in previous line). 
I then wanted to set all colors with red=green=blue (all grays from black to white) to black, so that only the blue line remains. 
I do this by subtracting, for every pixel, the average of the R, G and B-values from each of them. If they are equal, all become zero.

`.mean(axis=2)` calculates the average, making a 2d-array;
`.reshape()` makes it 3d again, by just adding a 3. dim of len 1;
`.repeat()` resets the shape of the array to that of `im`

Answer (score 1):

First, read the image via

```
from scipy.misc import imread    
im = imread("thefile.png")
```

This gives a 3D numpy array with the third dimension being the color channels (RGB+alpha). The curve is in the blue channel, but the grid is there also. But in the red channel, you have the grid and not the curve. So we use

```
a = im[:,:,2] - im[:,:,0]
```

Now, we want the position of the maximum along each column. With one pixel precision, it is given by

```
y0 = np.argmax(a, axis=0)
```

The result of this is zero when there is no blue curve in the column , i.e. outside the frame. On can get the limits of the frame by

```
xmin, xmax = np.where(y0>0)[0][[0,-1]
```

With this, you may be able to rescale x axis.

Then, you want subpixel resolution. Let us focus on a single column

```
f=a[:,x]
```

We use a single iteration of the Newton method to refine the position of an extrema

```
y1 = y0 - f'[y]/f''[y]
```

Note that we cannot iterate further because of the discreet sampling. Nontheless, we want a good approximation of the derivatives, so we will use a 5-point scheme for both.

```
coefprime = np.array([1,-8, 0, 8, -1], float)
coefsec = np.array([-1, 16, -30, 16, -1], float)
y1 = y0 - np.dot(f[y0-2:y0+3], coefprime)/np.dot(f[y0-2:y0+3], coefsec)
```

P.S. : Thorsten Kranz was faster than me (at least here), but my answer has the subpixel precision and my way of extracting the blue curve is probably more understandable.